# $\sum _{i=1}^n \sum _{j=1}^n x_i x_j a_{i,j}$ same as quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the quadratic forms equation:

[image]

I was wondering if the summation would be equal to:

$$\sum _{i=1}^n \sum _{j=1}^n x_i x_j a_{i,j}$$

Or is there a special reason to represent the sum in the first line different?

Comment: If you are asking about the order of the summations, then no.  For finite summations, the order may always be interchanged.  And if you are only talking about $a_{ij}x_ix_j$ and $x_ix_ja_{ij}$, then again no.  The commutative property prevails.

Comment: @Dr.MV Okey would you be able to explain i,j=1 what that means cause I have not seen this representation before.

Comment: It means that you will sum over both $i$ and $j$ starting from $1$ to $n$.  The single summation sign with two referenced indices means a double summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\sum{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j$ is just short hand notation. We can write the sum as

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j$$